# delete all users of a group

Tags: powershell, membership

I am trying to get a list of groups from a csv and for each group, delete all its group members and all groups it is a member of(nested) and I am stumped. My code partially works, if I only have 3 or 4 groups in the csv it seems to remove all memberships, but when I have 150 groups in the csv, it only does the first couple. I also tried changing "get-content" to "import-csv" with no luck. I am stumped. Any Ideas? My attempts are listed below;

```
get-content "$executingScriptDirectory\groups.csv" | foreach{Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$_.Name" |  Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf "$_" -Confirm:$false }


Groups = import-csv "$executingScriptDirectory\groups.csv"

ForEach ($Group In $Groups) {get-adgroupmember | remove-adgroupmember -identity $Group -members "$_"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that allow you to sove your problem using [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299745.aspx). It allows you to find recursively all the users of a group. I test it on PowerShell 3.0 on a W2K12 server.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$ctx = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext  ([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, "localhost:389", "OU=MonOU,DC=SILOGIX-ESS01,DC=local", "administrator", "administratorPwd")
$theGroup = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($ctx, "MonGrp")
$users = $theGroup.GetMembers($true)
```

It also exists another solution using PowerShell 2.0 using System.DirectoryServices and LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN. I'll post it if you can't use this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but i do not have powershell 3.0 only 2.0.